# How to compare two csv files in windows

Tags: windows, csv, excel-2010

I need to compare two csv files in windows7.
How can I proceed to achieve this. I want to see the differences in both the files , like we can use tkdiff in Linux.

Comment: yup , I tried Google  but did not find any satisfactory answers , That's why I asked here :P

Comment: You can also use notepad++ 's compare plugin.

Comment: Comparing 2 csvs is actually quite hard as you have to escape each field correctly and also you are likely to want to compare each line based on a key and not line by line which generic text comparisons do.

Comment: `zsv` has a `compare` feature that is fast, open-source and cross-platform (disclaimer: I'm one of the authors): https://github.com/liquidaty/zsv/blob/main/docs/compare.md

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Suggestion:

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> shortcut to open windows' Run prompt
- Type in `cmd` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open a <s>DOS terminal</s> cmd window
- Change the current path by running the command `cd C:\path\to\your\directory` to reach the location of the two CSV files

**Tip**: To paste a copied path from clipboard into <s>DOS terminal</s> cmd window, you can either (1) right-click on terminal window, or (2) press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>.

- Finally, to compare the two files, run `fc filename1.csv filename2.csv > outfile.txt` (`fc` stands for "file compare").
  The command will also log the result of comparison into a text file `outfile.txt` located in the same folder. If `outfile.txt` doesn't exist, it will be created automatically.

Comment: `fc` is a horrific file comparison tool. Try it yourself: Create two identical csv files and save them, and then add a new first line to one of them, and see what happens.

Answer (score 8):

Here is another option which I found very useful, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36315557/6340496):

`findstr /v /g:"file1.csv" "file2.csv"`

Where the `/v` switch returns the differences and `/g:` gets the search strings from file1.csv.  You can use `findstr /?` for more help.

You can also **print the differences to a file** using:

`findstr /v /g:"file1.csv" "file2.csv > diffs.csv"`

As an aside, I found `findstr` far more accurate and the output more readable than `fc`.

**UPDATE**
This works nicely with 'smaller' files.  You might get an `out of memory` error on larger files.  In this case, I've had to turn to Python and dataframes.  Just a friendly heads up ...

Answer (score 3):

I did this today.

Lets say we have 2 csv files X and Y

X having columns a, b, c
Y having column  a, b, c

The rows are not in same order and are disperesed througout the csv files.

I imported both of them in my excel sheet.
I sorted them first by column c and then by column b and then by column a.
You can go in any order you like.

Compare the sorted files through notepad++'s compare plugin/Beyond Compare.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and for fun I tried writing some powershell code to generate a "per column" diff. It is embarrassingly slow, but it solved my problem nicer (very wide CSV file, so regular diff was really hard to interpret). Call `Compare-Csv` with the files you need

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

function Compare-Csv
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)] [string] $ReferenceFile,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)] [string] $DifferenceFile,
    [string[]] $ReferenceIdentifiers = $null,
    [char] $Delimiter = ';'
)
{
    $referenceData = Import-Csv -ErrorAction 'Stop' -Delimiter $Delimiter $ReferenceFile
    $differenceData = Import-Csv -ErrorAction 'Stop' -Delimiter $Delimiter $DifferenceFile
    $referenceDataHeaders = [string[]] ($referenceData | Select-Object -First 1 | Get-Member -MemberType Properties | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)
    $differenceDataHeaders = [string[]] ($differenceData | Select-Object -First 1 | Get-Member -MemberType Properties | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)
    $supersetHeaders = ($referenceDataHeaders + $differenceDataHeaders) | Select-Object -Unique

    $empty = @()
    $fileDifferences = @()
    $maxLength = ($referenceData.Length, $differenceData.Length | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum
    for($i = 0; $i -lt $maxLength; $i++)
    {
        $ref = $empty;
        if($i -lt $referenceData.Length)
        {
            $ref = $referenceData[$i]
        }

        $diff = $empty;
        if($i -lt $differenceData.Length)
        {
            $diff = $differenceData[$i]
        }

        $rowDifferences = $null
        foreach($header in $supersetHeaders)
        {
            $compare = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $ref -DifferenceObject $diff -Property $header
            if($compare)
            {
                if(-not $rowDifferences)
                {
                    $rowDifferences = @{}
                    if($ReferenceIdentifiers)
                    {
                        $identifer = ($ref | Select-Object -Property $ReferenceIdentifiers).PSObject.Properties.Value
                        $rowDifferences.Add('ReferenceIdentifiers', $identifer)
                    }
                }

                $rowDifferences.Add($header, $compare)
            }
        }

        if($rowDifferences)
        {
            $fileDifferences + $rowDifferences
        }
    }

    return $fileDifferences
}

$differences = Compare-Csv -ReferenceFile 'Ref.csv' -DifferenceFile 'Diff.csv' -ReferenceIdentifiers @('ARRAY OF HEADER NAMES USED TAKEN FROM REFERENCE FILE THAT CAN BE USED TO IDENTIFY THE ROW')
foreach($difference in $differences)
{
    $out = $difference.ReferenceIdentifiers + ": " + ($difference | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty ReferenceIdentifiers | Format-List | Out-String -NoNewline)
    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host $out
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the same thing with Powershell, which can be useful if you're in a read-only folder.

```
compare-object -ReferenceObject (Get-Content filename1.CSV) -DifferenceObject (Get-content filename2.CSV)
```

You can launch Powershell directly in your folder without navigating via cd, by typing powershell in the folder's address bar.