# Batch file to compare the differences in two csv files

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file, windows-7

I use windows 7.
I have two csv files file1.csv and file2.csv

file1.csv

```
emp_id;salary
1;1000
2;2000
3;3000
```

file.csv

```
emp_id;salary
1;1000
2;2000
3;3000
4;4000
5;5000
```

I'm confused how to write a batch file.
The batch file should output the should be a csv file showing the changes.

Sample output:

```
emp_id;salary
4;4000
5;5000
```

Comment: There is a UNIX command named diff. Check if you can use it in Windows. Certainly will be possible with Cygwin

Comment: Use `comp`. Run `comp /?` from the command line to see it's parameters.

Comment: I tried using fc in batch file. Error: FC cannot open file or folder

Comment: Do you want to show the lines in file2.csv that are not in file1.csv? Or also the opposite case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `findstr` to look for differences, and the `/v` parameter to display differences. Like so:

```
findstr /v /g:"file1.csv" "file2.csv"
```

Also:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (file1.csv) do (
    findstr "^%%a$" "file2.csv" >nul ||echo %%a
)
```

And using the `fc` command:

```
fc "file1.csv" "file2.csv"
```

For `fc` im sure you can use an `if not errorlevel 1 echo No difference`

Comment: I'm sure, you can not. `if errorlevel 0` is true for "zero or greater". `if not errorlevel 1 echo no difference` works.

Comment: Thanks, edited, i typically just use the variable under controlled environments.

Comment: thanks for sharing this. Still valid in 2022. With Tableau commandline and SSIS 2019.