# Need to check .CSV's one column against another .CSV one column for matches

Tags: python, csv, awk, sed, grep

I have one CSV that is 10,000 or so rows. all one field

```
.000.000.000
.111.111.111
etc
```

I need to check the above against a master list of 400,000 or so rows, once again all one field

```
.0
.1
.3
and up
```

What would be the best way? I tried a grep with -f but I feel it didn't do anything

```
grep -f [file1][file2]
```

it returned no results but I also didn't give a output which I think it needed.

I also tried a awk but it was just something I found and don't really understand it. So once again didn't get the results I wanted.

```
awk -F, 'NR>1&&NR==FNR{a[$1];next}FNR>1&&($1 in a){print $1,"in both!"}'
```

I would like to make it a script if possible, but if not the simpler the better. I am really doing this check for diligence but I am 90% sure my small list will have no lines matching in the large file. But I need some sort of confirmation when check that is the case.

Comment: post a more testable/extended input samples and expected result

Comment: check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33523362/how-to-compare-two-csv-files-in-windows other way use with notepad++

Comment: Mac user that sounds like a decent way

Comment: Why are you calling these files CSVs when there's just 1 field in each file? Either they are CSVs and there's something you're not sharing with us about your input files, or they aren't CSVs,

Comment: they were larger files with more fields but I removed all the other fields.. so it is just the format that the files are currently saved as..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`grep` seems like it should work. Seems like `grep -Fx -f [searchfile] [matchfile]` (-F to indicate string not regex matching, and -x to force the whole line to be matched) should do what you want?

E.g.

```
$ cat grepsearch.txt
000.000
111.111
222.333

$ cat greptest.txt
1
2
41
5
235
15
15
000.000.00
431
5341
643
16
43
000.000
3251235
431
5431
543
1
543
15341
111.111
435143
54
35
43
11111
1111111
11111
111111
0000000
00000
222.333
432
145
3415
431
543

$ grep -F -f grepsearch.txt greptest.txt
000.000
111.111
222.333
```

Note without -F/-x the `.`'s are being interpreted as regex:

```
$ grep -f grepsearch.txt greptest.txt
000.000
111.111
1111111
0000000
222.333
```

Comment: I feel this is good.. the grep ran for like a hour and then came back empty.. if it had matches it would display them correct?

Comment: you are **not covering a case** that string is **sub string in file 2** . for example:  file2 includes `000.000.00`   . your solution will recognize it as a string in file1 (what will print the string as the same)

Comment: You are correct @shaikisiegal - thanks for pointing that out. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
  awk '{if(NR==FNR){a[$0]++} else {if (a[$0])print "in both " $0}}' file1 file2
```

1. `if(NR==FNR)` - check if line is read from the first line, insert value to be used as key in dictionary and increment the value of this key `a[$0]++` (`$0` -key, `++` inc value)
2. `else`    `if (a[$0])`   check if a dictionary includes a key named `$0` (checking if line have exists in the first file )
3. if line  exists `print "in both " $0` (print "in both" string and the value found in both)

Comment: tried that but it went super fast think I might have used it wrong

Comment: awk is really efficient. what is the size of your files?

Comment: 138KB 10k lines searching in 5.9MB file 400,000 lines

Comment: i have tested it on 2 files:

Comment: created both files with seq command. all numbers from 1 to  10000000  & 20000000 :  `seq 1 1 10000000 > file1 `  ,  `seq 1 1 20000000 > file2 `  .    `**76M** Feb 14 00:16 file1`, `**162M** Feb 14 00:16 file2` . **for the size of your files it should take no time**

Comment: for `seq 1 1 25000 > file2  to get`  **~ 138KB and 25K lines**,                                                      `seq 1 1 1000000 > file1~ to get` **~ 6.6MB and 1M lines**, running awk command with time check takes **0.132s**