# How to compare two csv files and print all the differences

Tags: python, csv

I have two csv files `(old.csv and new.csv)` with lot of data in them. Both the csv files have same data but ordering can be different for each row. `old.csv` file act as the source file. I am tyring to compare both the csv files to see if any row is missing or any new row is there.

- Compare `old.csv` with `new.csv` and see if any row is missing in `new.csv` or any new row is present in `new.csv`. Each row should exactly match in both the csv's.

Below code I have only checks for new row in `new.csv` which is not present in `old.csv` but how can we also check for all other things.

```
with open('old.csv', 'r') as t1, open('new.csv', 'r') as t2:
    fileone = t1.readlines()
    filetwo = t2.readlines()

with open('update.csv', 'w') as outFile:
    for line in filetwo:
        if line not in fileone:
            outFile.write(line)
```

Basically both `old.csv` and `new.csv` files should exactly match with everything like content (each row), number of entries and other things. There should not be any difference between these two files.

Comment: Why not just run a diff on the two files?

Comment: If both files fit in memory at the same time you can simply put the lines of each file in a set and apply set operations on them.

Comment: yeah it can fit in memory. Just few mb's of file.

Comment: If you happen to be on Windows, here a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45591193/6340496). If on *nix, what about `diff`, as mentioned in an earlier comment.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Can you provide an example with the set based approach?

Comment: Editing Questions to improve them (e.g. clarification, adding additional information, etc.) *is encouraged*. However, editing a Question to change it into a different question, which invalidates one or more answers, is against policy on Stack Overflow. Your edit here did so. The policy is that other users with edit privileges should proactively revert such changes. I have reverted your edit. You *are encouraged to [ask a new Question](/questions/ask)*, perhaps with a link to this one for additional context. We want to help, but your new/additional issue needs to be a new Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using difflib for this, but it will have the same limitations as command-line diff.  It can report a line as "new" when it's merely moved.

Assuming order isn't important, the set-based approach is probably what you need.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: yeah set based approach sounds good. Can you provide an example with the set based approach?

Comment: set(fileone).symmetric_difference(filetwo) will give you a tuple with the lines unique to fileone at [0] and all the lines unique to filetwo at [1].

Comment: @AaronBentley I updated my question with what I have tried. It gives me error as of now.